# How to Get 2 Return values in one Function

Tags: vb.net

I want to get two output values in one Function is't possible ?.
I am just using String data type and split the values.
but have any other easy way to get two output values...

Actually I want to checking a folder how many jpg files are Horizontal and vertical 
so

```
Public Function HVChecking() as string
  Dim HCount%, VCount%
  '' 
  ''
  ''
  ''
 Return HCount.ToString & "|" & VCount.ToString
End Function
```

finally I split the values with "|" character...

have any other options to get two values as separate in one functions.

I have no idea about Dictionary, HashTable... Which one is best for this?

Comment: Usually, for getting a function to return 2 values, it's accomplished by returning an array: `[value1, value2]`. I think it's the most common way to do it in most languages.

Comment: ya ya ya got it .....Structure omg i forgot it one........ThnQ Chris,Zheileman,Mustafa........

Comment: Ever wonder why we can code our own data types? Like `class` or `struct`

Answer (score 1):

I think you can send two ByRef Parameter to the Function. I mean,

```
Public Sub HVChecking(ByRef HCount as Integer, ByRef VCount as Integer)
```

And you can call the function as

```
Dim HCount%, VCount%
HVChecking(HCount, Vcount)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are data types that exist in the framework to encapsulate two integers, [`Point`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534487%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) immedaitely springs to mind.

If you wanted to add some context you could create your own [Class or Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2hkbth2a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

As a last resort, or if you don't have time to type 4 lines, you could use `ByRef` parameters. These can give good performance but, they are the legacy approach for [good reason](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ByRefConsideredHarmful).